# Sort HTML Data in DIV tags

Tags: jquery, html, sorting

For my html , i dont have the data in tables , but they are structured in  tags

its is something like

```
<div id="1"> name=abc id=501  </div>
<div id="2"> name=sdc id=502  </div>
<div id="3"> name=xyz id=503  </div>
```

Can i sort this using jquery/javascript php anything ! ?

Note the number of  are variable , i.e  decieded dynamically

Comment: Sorted by what? `name`, `id`, something else?

Comment: make it `<div id='1' data-name='abc' data-id='501'></div` easier parsing and value retrieval. http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Do you have a json object? just to know.

Comment: i want to sort by name and id both , i have to design a drop down for the same

Comment: @nbrooks buddy thanks for the code its what i wanted but the $('#sorter').append($('#'+val.htmlId)); is troublesome i have to display the data in the same div itself i cannot generate a new div like before('<div id="sorter"></div>') so the append gives me a error like : "HierarchyRequestError: Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4U6N/5/)

I changed your html to use data-attributes (the correct way to store data in your markup); it now looks like this `<div id='2' data-name='sdc' data-id='502'>sdc</div>`. This also allows jQuery to retrieve the property readily using the [`.data()` method](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

**This sorts by name. To sort by id instead, change `return a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1;` to `return a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1;`**

```
$(function() {
    var alphaSort = $("div").map(function() {
        return {
            htmlId: this.id,
            name: $(this).data('name'),
            id: $(this).data('id')
        };
    }).toArray().sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.name > b.name ? 1: -1;
    });

    $.each(alphaSort, function(i, val) {
        if( $('div[data-name]').last().is('#'+val.htmlId) ) {
            return true; //continue               
        }
        $('div[data-name]').last().after($('#'+val.htmlId));
    });
});​
```

Comment: what is .data(name) ? in my example could you relate and tell me please ?

Comment: I think this is not working, I get "undefined" and the array "[]" check your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/Q4U6N/

Comment: @user1537158 jQuery can retrieve data attributes from elements http://api.jquery.com/data/ (must have data as `data-name=''`, etc)

Comment: @nbrooks your jsfiddle does not reder abc->sdc->xyz if i put text as sdc->xyz->abc between the DIV tags, not working for me

Comment: I was just generating an array, not changing the actual DOM (didn't know you wanted that. Changed it, see demo.

Comment: @nbrooks buddy thanks for the code its what i wanted but the $('#sorter').append($('#'+val.htmlId));
is troublesome i have to display the data in the same div itself i cannot generate a new div like before('<div id="sorter"></div>') so the append gives me a error like :
"HierarchyRequestError: Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy"

Comment: @user1537158 It will stay in the same div at the end (I get rid of the extra div using `.unwrap()`) so the final location is the same

Comment: it has bug it's wrong action :: return a.name > b.name;
you fix the code like this :: if( a.name > b.name ) return -1 ) ... see my answer's sort body.

Comment: @user1537158 What's the reason for the constraint (i.e. what system is giving you that error)? You can't rewrite the dom elements if you're not allowed to do appends

Comment: @blueiur That's not a 'bug', it works just fine. (although I'm not positive all browsers' implementations accept `true`/`false` as output, so thanks for the heads up). If you take a look at the demo (and try swapping `>` and `<`) you can see that it sorts correctly.

Comment: @user1537158 check my answer and example, maybe could help you :-)

Comment: @nbrooks firebug on mozilla firebox gives me that error, i have no constraints of appending dom elements as such

Comment: @user1537158 Okay, well I updated my answer to not use the additional div.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know you absolute want but i try 
it' sort by id then sort by name.

http://jsfiddle.net/k9aPj/3/

```
// html
<div id='container'>    
    <div id="3"> name=xyz id=503  </div>
    <div id="1"> name=abc id=501  </div>
    <div id="2"> name=sdc id=502  </div>
</div>


// js code
var parent = document.getElementById('container');
var childs = parent.childNodes;
childs = Array.prototype.slice.call(childs).filter(function(el){
        return el.nodeName == "DIV";
     });

childs.sort(function(a, b){    
    var aValues = a.innerText.split(' ');
    var aName = aValues[0].split("=")[1];
    var aId = aValues[1].split("=")[1];

    var bValues = b.innerText.split(' ');
    var bName = bValues[0].split("=")[1];
    var bId = bValues[1].split("=")[1];

    if( aName != bName ){
       if (aName > bName) return 1;
       if (aName < bName) return -1;
       return parseInt(aId) - parseInt(bId); // sort by id
    }    
});

container.innerHTML = childs.map(function(el){
    return el.outerHTML;
}).join('');

//result is 
name=abc id=501
name=sdc id=502
name=xyz id=503
```

​

​

Comment: no no i want to sort either by id or by name, can u give me a jsfiddle where if put sdc->xyz->abc between the respective DIV tags i get abc->sdc->xyz ?

Comment: buddy its not rendering the sorted array the names are rendered as sdc 
xyz 
abc 

i want to display sorted

Comment: it  rendered  by  sorted  see  my  comment`s  link

Comment: nop buddy i still see the result as :
name=sdc id=502
name=xyz id=503
name=abc id=501

Comment: no no  result  is  right  bottom  pannel.  you  see  unsorted  data it`s  for  test

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do better using this way and also have the ids and names sorted as you need.

**Live DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/VJ3ZR/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="3"> name=xyz id=503  </div>
<div id="1"> name=abc id=501  </div>
<div id="2"> name=sdc id=502  </div>
```

**​JS:**

```
var arrName = new Array();
var arrId = new Array();

$(function(){

    $('div').map(function(){
        var data = $(this).text().match(/name=(.*) id=(.*)/);
        arrName.push($.trim(data[1]));
        arrId.push(parseInt($.trim(data[2])));      
    });

    arrName.sort();
    arrId.sort();

    alert('Sorted names: ' + arrName + '\nSorted ids: ' + arrId);
});
```

**Output:**

> Sorted names: abc,sdc,xyz / Sorted ids: 501,502,503

Comment: all right that was neat , but can i display the sorted div after i get the sorted arrays arrName and arrId ?

Comment: no no i want to display the appropriate div in sorted order not sorted values